# How to find the auto suggestion on google search with Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

With Selenium webdriver, I am trying search 'Selenium' in google search box, which provides auto suggestions of several texts. Then I am trying to click one particular text from auto suggestions list. It seems though, my Xpath is not working.

Below is the code I wrote:

```
package com.initial.selenium;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class GoogleSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\Shahid\\eclipse-
    workspace\\InitialSeleniumProject\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='q']")).sendKeys("selenium");
        List < WebElement >

            mylist=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class='sbl1']/span"));
        System.out.println(mylist.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(mylist.get(i).getText());
            if (mylist.get(i).getText().contains("Selenium Benefits")) {
                mylist.get(i).click();
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: what does _not working_ mean?

Comment: The script results 0

Comment: Did you try webdriverwait?

Comment: @ShahidIslam use this xpath - //ul[@class='erkvQe']//li and fetch text from it. it will return span text.

Comment: @Dhru 'Soni: thank you. That has done the trick. I still do not understand why my xpath was not working. If you can, please, indicate any problem with my xpath, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @ShahidIslam i run it with your xpath and thats also correctly working form me but i am not able to found "Selenium benefits" in suggestive as it is not show in suggestive for me it will work for selenium python and other sub suggestives.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<WebElement> options = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/descendant::span"), 0));

    System.out.println("no. of suggestions:"+options.size());
    
    for(int i=0;i<options.size();i++) {
        
        System.out.println(options.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the error you're getting (**a null result**) is because the *ul element* you're targeting **doesn't contain any elements.**

[image: Image displaying that the target ul doesn't contain any children]

So, in this case, you're going to change your target. Instead of doing:

```
ul[@role='listbox']
```

Do

```
li[@role='presentation']
```

And that will result in

```
//li[@role='presentation']/descendant::div[@class='sbl1']/span
```

Which returns the span you're trying to get.

Comment: With this xpath, the script results 1

Comment: I still cannot find what is wrong with my xpath. However, none of the suggested xpath including mine are provide intended result. I would appreciate any other help